# Frequency and Period of a JK flip-flop circuit

Tags: clock, flipflop, pulse

**Reposting this question from Electric Engineering. Wouldn't normally do this but I have to figure out this concept by tomorrow. Thanks in advance for any answers.**

I am currently working through the problem as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffJHdn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

While it makes sense to me why output signals Q0 and Q1 are set to high aside from pulses which coincide with the dropping of CLK, the answer key states that the frequency and wavelength of the input clock is equal to that of the outputs. This is very confusing to me. Shouldn't the wavelength of output signal be equal to 2*wavelength of input signal?

Comment: I think we should rather close the other question as a dupe of this one.

Answer (score 3):

The outputs will only switch at the falling edge of clock if these are negative edge triggered flip flops.

Here is a simulation example (with negative edge triggered JK flip flops):

[image: falstad simulation div3]

You can see the output is related to the input by a factor of three (divide by three circuit).  The pulse width is twice the input clock pulse width.

Answer (score 0):

The text is wrong. In fact, one doesn't even have to understand how the flip-flop works as long as one understand that since the clock has an effect only when it goes high, it can't have an effect when it goes low, and therefore nothing can happen then--which means an output wouldn't change state, which means it couldn't possibly have the same frequency. On a side note, I believe this divides the frequency by three, but one should simulate it to be sure.

(BTW, the diagram shows an active-high clock, not active low, but in either case the text is wrong)